# how to draw RGBA point on stage?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, pixel, draw, point

so we have values generator that outputs someting like `FF00FF5F`. We have some coordinates like `50, 300`. We want to draw on stage. (I mean we opened new `.fla` doc in flash, pressed f9 and started coding, sorry - I am new to flash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need [`BitmapData.setPixel()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#setPixel32%28%29)